# MySQL How to calculate checkpoint age?

Tags: mysql

According to the Percona article MySQL checkpoint age may freeze it:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/04/innodb-flushing-theory-and-solutions/

How can I calculate it?
How can I ensure that innodb_log_file_size of 134 mb is enough for me or I need to increase it?

This is the section LOG from SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, but what is the correct formula?
( and how do I get megabytes to compare with innodb_log_file_size )

```
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number          26361002986468
Log buffer assigned up to    26361002986468
Log buffer completed up to   26361002986148
Log written up to            26361002986148
Log flushed up to            26361002902700
Added dirty pages up to      26361002986148
Pages flushed up to          26360959010673
Last checkpoint at           26360958543063
7934296064 log i/o's done, 669.00 log i/o's/second
```

Thanks.

P.S  We are thinking should we increase innodb_capacity_io from default 200 to, lets say, 500 or 1000. ( we have enough iops available )

Comment: `innodb_log_file_size` is tricky to increase.  First, what version are you using?  And is it in a cloud?

Comment: Yes, MySQL AWS RDS 8.0.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sequence numbers are necessarily large, monotonically increasing, numbers.  They are not byte offsets into the log.  You may find the number in the log, if you have fun with hex dumps.  (I don't.)

That Percona blog, while good, is a decade old.  A large log no longer delays restart as much as it once did.

Consider this for judging whether to increase (or decrease) the log_file_size:

Minutes between InnoDB log rotations = `Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written`

60 minutes is a good target, but it is not a precise target.

Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change `my.cnf`.

`innodb_log_files_in_group` traditionally has been 2.  I suggest you use 2 unless you are on a new version of MariaDB, where it is no longer needed.

Comment: Hi Rick. Tnx for the answer.
In the reality, I still have a problem described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289495/mysql-freezes-every-hour-at-the-exact-same-time

You have left few comments there as well.

So I am continuing to research what could be the issue and thought that to verify checkpoint age.

Comment: To be honest, I am thinking should I increase innodb_capacity_io from default 200 to, lets say, 500 or 1000. ( we have enough iops available )

Comment: @user3489820 - Yes, raise it, especially if the disk is SSD, which is very likely to be the case on AWS.  Also, AWS may not allow changing the log_file_size.  Check with them; my info could be out of date.

Comment: Well, if I make Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total * 100, I will get 0.8%....

Whereas I can increase innodb_capacity_io, but it doesn't look it will help me.
Correct my understanding if I am wrong please.

Comment: @user3489820 - I recommend 30% for that formula.  There is no need to try to improve on 0.8%.  What is the value of your `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct`?

Comment: innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90 ( default ).
anyway, I just increased innodb_io_capacity to 500 from 200, didn't help much :)

Comment: @user3489820 - Do you have evidence that you are I/O-bound?

Comment: Yes & No :) 

Yes - because we see a Disk Await & Avg Queue Size spikes during glitch.
No - because IOPS are significantly below the needed.

AWS for now keeps telling that disks are fine.